# Reading the same line from a file many times in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I would like to read the same line of a file many time in Fortran. The concerned data are real values. I tried to build this code as test but I am always getting it wrong.

```
program advance

    implicit none
    integer , parameter :: ut = 20
    character(len=7) :: fname = 'dat.dat'
    integer :: n, idx 
    character(len=100) :: lnumber 
    open(unit = ut, file =fname, status='old', action='read')

    n = 10 

    do idx = 1, n 
        read(ut, '(a)', advance = 'no') lnumber 
        print *, lnumber 
    end do 

end program advance
```

The `dat.dat` file contains one line with `25.325654515464564564`

The code return the following error.

```
At line 13 of file advance.f90 (unit = 20, file = 'dat.dat')
Fortran runtime error: End of record
```

How do I fix this bug?

Comment: Are you thinking that using `advance='no'` means that the file remains positioned at the _beginning_ of the line when it has been read?

Comment: Reading the same line many times is almost certainly not the right approach, whatever you are trying to do.  It is almost certainly better to read the line once and to process it, if you want to, many times.  Don't though, let my scepticism about the utility of your approach, stop you.

Comment: Yes, normally the pointer should remain fixed. Have a look at the specification of the read statement in Fortan [link](http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfenthelp/F95ARREADStmt.htm). Maybe, I am wrong on the way I am using it.

Comment: The link you provided does not indicate that 'the pointer should remain fixed'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such *non-advancing* input (using `advance='no'`) doesn't mean that the file position is not advanced at all.  It means that the file position isn't advanced *beyond what is needed* to satisfy the requirements of the input list.

So, in this case, the file position is advanced by reading the single "real number" into the character variable `lnumber`.  The next read will continue from this later point.  This later point happens to be the end of the file.

With *advancing* input more generally, the file position is advanced to the start of the next record even if the record is not required in entirety.

---

As High Performance Mark [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332396/reading-the-same-line-from-a-file-many-times-in-fortran#comment87680978_50332396), reading the same line over and over again likely isn't what you should be doing.  You could read the line into a character variable (such as is done here) and repeatedly use that variable as an *internal file*.  However, if you really want to read a line again, consider `backspace`.