# Writing data in a notepad file Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran, fortran95

I'm trying to do the following:

- Read from a txt file called "numbers", which is a file with 7 lines, 1 character per line. Line 1 has 1, Line 2 has 2, Line 3 has 3 and so on..
- Read each line, note whether it is positive or negative, state it, then, if it's positive, write it in txt file "positives" and if not, write it in txt file "negatives"

Here's my code:

```
program write
implicit none
integer :: i,x
open (12,file='numbers.txt')
    do i = 1,7
      read(12,*) x
        if (mod(x,2)>0) then
            open(11,file='negatives.txt')
            write (11,*) x
            print *, 'Negative!'
        else
            open(13,file='positives.txt')
            write (13,*) x
            print *, 'Positive!'
        end if
     end do
end program write
```

It correctly tells me which is positive and which is negative, but when I open "positives.txt" and "negatives.txt" they remain blank. How do I rectify this?

Also, I lucked out, but I thought given the code Fortran would read from the first line 7 times. Not read line 2 for i = 2 and line 3 for i = 3 and so on. Since I don't see anything in here telling it where to read from any line other than line 1. How does it know to do that?

Comment: Default behavior of Fortran I/O is 'Advance', that's why it jumps to the next record. You could change that in the read statement if you wanted to

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Just out of curiosity, how would I change that?

Comment: read(12, *, advance='no') x More info on software.intel.com/en-us/node/693756

Comment: Note that such non-advancing read [won't result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50332396/3157076) in the first line being read more than once.  It would have an effect only when there is more than one item on a single line.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any simple, Fortran-related explanation to the behaviour you are describing (all iterations of the loop executed but no output to the files and no error message reported) - the only ones I can think of have to do with the file system or the operating system (e.g., NFS malfunction), and still should be showing up in the form of errors.

However,

1. You say that you want to write positive and negative numbers in different files, but the condition you are using to decide whether `x` is positive or negative is `mod(x,2)>0`, which uses the Fortran remainder function https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm.  If you want to check whether x is positive or negative, you should directly compare `x` with `0`, and decide what you want to output when the input is zero (which usually is considered neither positive nor negative).
2. Your `open` statements do not specify any `action`, the possibilities being `read`, `write`, or `readwrite`.  If no action is specified, the Fortran standard states that the default is compiler dependent, so you could end up with an output file that you are not allowed to write to.  In your case, you should really specify `action=read` when opening file `numbers.txt` and `action=write` when opening files `negatives.txt` and `positives.txt`.
3. If you want to read a line (record, in Fortran lore) multiple consecutive times, you should use the `backspace` statement after each read that you want to repeat, followed by the unit number of the file concerned.  I cannot make much sense of this in your case (wanting to read 7 times the first line of a 7-line file is quite counter-intuitive), but that's the way to go.
4. By having the `open` statement within each iteration, your code uses a valid strategy to prevent creating a file if no output to that file will happen in the program.  However, bear in mind that there is no need to `open` the file before every `write`, you could only do that once per file.  It is also good coding practice to explicitly `close` all the files that you `open`.

With all these changes, the code would look like this:

```
program write
    implicit none
    integer :: i,x
    logical :: p_open, n_open
    p_open = .false. ; n_open = .false.
    open (12,file='numbers.txt',action='read')
    do i = 1,7
        read(12,*) x
        if (x<0) then
            if (.not. n_open) then
                open(11,file='negatives.txt',action='write')
                n_open = .true.
            end if
            write (11,*) x
            print *, 'Negative!'
        else if (x>0) then
            if (.not. p_open) then
                open(13,file='positives.txt',action='write')
                p_open = .true.
            end if
            write (13,*) x
            print *, 'Positive!'
        else ! x==0
            print *, 'Zero found!!'
        end if
        backspace 12
    end do
    if (n_open) close(11)
    if (p_open) close(13)
    close(12)
end program write
```

Comment: For some reason, copy and pasting this code and running it isn't working -- it compiles fine but when I try to run it the terminal appears for a split second then vanishes - and no licensing message appears. Any idea why that is?

Comment: The fact that you say that the terminal "appears" suggests that it was not present in the beginning, and that you are running the binary from a graphical environment (by double-clicking on it or other analogous method).  Is that the case?  If yes, can you try running the binary from a terminal, and reporting what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

Just put open(11,file='negatives.txt') and open(13,file='positives.txt') out of the do loop would solve your problem. Besides, your code is to identify even or odd numbers rather than positive or negative numbers.
Just need to make a little modification to your code:

```
program write
implicit none
integer :: i,x
open(12,file='numbers.txt')
open(11,file='negatives.txt')
open(13,file='positives.txt')
    do i = 1,7
      read(12,*) x
        if (x < 0) then
            write (11,*) x
            print *, 'Negative!'
        elseif (x > 0) then
            write (13,*) x
            print *, 'Positive!'
        else
            print *, 'This is zero.'
        end if
     end do
end program write
```

This should work.